Static `div` and `table` taking all space with sticked headers
I need to add a component which will take all available space assigned to it.
It should be split into 2 parts.

Toolbar panel - always visible on top
Table - with  headers always visible on the screen, stacked to top.

So when there are a lot of rows in the table I should see a scroll, which will scroll only tbody, ie panel and table headers should stay on the screen.
I need CSS-only solution, without additional JS calculations
Here is what I have (and it does not work)
https://jsfiddle.net/vqsfhm4e/1/
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.top-panel {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.table-container {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

 <div className="container">
      <div className="top-panel">
        <h2>Top Panel</h2>
        <p>This content is always visible, as well as headers for table.</p>
      </div>
      <div className="table-container">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Header 1</th>
              <th>Header 2</th>
              <th>Header 3</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {tableData.map((row) => (
              <tr key={row.id}>
                <td>{row.col1}</td>
                <td>{row.col2}</td>
                <td>{row.col3}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>


Is this what you're after? https://jsfiddle.net/hvdfrgs8/ if so let me know and I can add an answer with explanation.

I see your code, it is done with javascript which is not an option for me

Here is a better solution if you only want css. https://jsfiddle.net/z7Ltca1r/1/ is this what you are after?

If you are looking for a CSS only solution, you can add a position of sticky to the elements you wish to stay on top. By adding a top position of '0' to the lower element they will stack on top of each other.
I changed the overflow: hidden in your table-container style to overflow-x so the y axis can scroll.
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.top-panel {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  /* add position sticky so it will stay at the top of the page 
  */
  position: sticky;
}
.table-container {
  flex: 1;
  /* changed overfow hidden to overflow-x hidden so 
     overflow-y can scroll from its set top position. 
  */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  /* add position sticky so it will stay at the top of the page 
  */
  position: sticky;
  /* top position assures element will stick when it 
     gets to the stacking order of sticky elements 
  */
  top: 0;
}
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}
tbody {
  /* allow overflow on the y axis to scroll
  */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: block;
}
thead,
tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
thead {
  width: calc(100% - 1em); /* Adjust for scrollbar width */
}

Here is a link to your JSFiddle snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/z7Ltca1r/2/
Below is an example:


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-panel {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  /* add position sticky so it will stay at the top of the page 
  */
  position: sticky;
}

.table-container {
  flex: 1;
  /* changed overfow hidden to overflow-x hidden so 
     overflow-y can scroll from its set top position. 
  */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  /* add position sticky so it will stay at the top of the page */
  position: sticky;
  /* top position assures element will stick when it 
     gets to the stacking order of sticky elements */
  top: 0;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

tbody {
  /* allow overflow on the y axis to scroll
  */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: block;
}

thead,
tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

thead {
  width: calc(100% - 1em);
  /* Adjust for scrollbar width */
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-panel">
    <h2>Top Panel</h2>
    <p>This content is always visible and can grow without affecting the tbody position.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>More 1</td>
          <td>Extra 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>More 2</td>
          <td>Extra 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>More 3</td>
          <td>Extra 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>More 4</td>
          <td>Extra 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>More 5</td>
          <td>Extra 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 6</td>
          <td>More 6</td>
          <td>Extra 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 7</td>
          <td>More 7</td>
          <td>Extra 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 8</td>
          <td>More 8</td>
          <td>Extra 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 9</td>
          <td>More 9</td>
          <td>Extra 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 10</td>
          <td>More 10</td>
          <td>Extra 10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 11</td>
          <td>More 11</td>
          <td>Extra 11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 12</td>
          <td>More 12</td>
          <td>Extra 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 13</td>
          <td>More 13</td>
          <td>Extra 13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 14</td>
          <td>More 14</td>
          <td>Extra 14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 15</td>
          <td>More 15</td>
          <td>Extra 15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 16</td>
          <td>More 16</td>
          <td>Extra 16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 17</td>
          <td>More 17</td>
          <td>Extra 17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 18</td>
          <td>More 18</td>
          <td>Extra 18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 19</td>
          <td>More 19</td>
          <td>Extra 19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 20</td>
          <td>More 20</td>
          <td>Extra 20</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>



